# How can I append a variable number of blank rows to a dataframe by group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, padding

I have a dataframe that looks like the following, with x number of person ids (more than 1000 persons), x number of transactions per person, and x number of variables (more than 1000 variables):

| Person_ID | transaction_ID | variable_1 | variable_2 | variable_3 | variable_X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| person1 | transaction1 | 123 | 0 | 1 | abc |
| person1 | transaction2 | 456 | 1 | 0 | def |
| person1 | transaction3 | 123 | 0 | 1 | abc |
| personx | transaction1 | 123 | 0 | 1 | abc |
| personx | transaction2 | 456 | 0 | 1 | def |

I want to pad it with rows containing -10 at the beginning of every person id group so that the total number of rows per person id group is 6, like the following:

| Person_ID | transaction_ID | variable_1 | variable_2 | variable_3 | variable_X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| person1 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 |
| person1 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 |
| person1 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 |
| person1 | transaction1 | 123 | 0 | 1 | abc |
| person1 | transaction2 | 456 | 1 | 0 | def |
| person1 | transaction3 | 123 | 0 | 1 | abc |
| personx | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 |
| personx | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 |
| personx | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 |
| personx | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 |
| personx | transaction1 | 123 | 0 | 1 | abc |
| personx | transaction2 | 456 | 0 | 1 | def |

Here is the code I tried (updated with concat) and the error below it.

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[''] * len(newdf.columns)], columns=newdf.columns)
df2
```

```py
for row in newdf.groupby('person_id')['transaction_id']:
   x=newdf.groupby('person_id')['person_id'].nunique()
   if x.any() < 6:
       newdf=pd.concat([newdf, df2*(6-x)], ignore_index=True)
```

```
RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects.
  newdf=pd.concat([newdf, df2*(6-x)], ignore_index=True)
```

It appended several NaN rows to the bottom of the dataframe, but not inbetween groups as needed. Thank you in advance as I am a beginner.

Comment: Might be better to use `concat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

use `groupby` + `apply`

```
def func1(df):
    n = 6 - len(df)
    if n > 0:
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['Person_ID'].iloc[0], columns=['Person_ID'], index=range(0, n))
        return pd.concat([df1.reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value=-10), df])
out = df.groupby('Person_ID', group_keys=False).apply(func1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

out

out

[image]

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Person_ID': ['person1', 'person1', 'person1', 'personx', 'personx'], 
         'transaction_ID': ['transaction1', 'transaction2', 'transaction3', 'transaction1', 'transaction2'], 
         'variable_1': [123, 456, 123, 123, 456], 
         'variable_2': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
         'variable_3': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
         'variable_X': ['abc', 'def', 'abc', 'abc', 'def']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `.concat()` instead of `.append()`.
And you can use `reindex()` to repeat the rows.

Try this example:

```
    import pandas as pd

data = [['Person1', 'transaction1', 803.5, 1],
 ['Person2', 'transaction2', 776.6, 2],
 ['Person3', 'transaction3', 3.9, 0],
 ['Person4', 'transaction1', 8.1, 7],
  ['Person5', 'transaction2', 1.7, 1],
  ['Person6', 'transaction3', 505.6, 2],
   ['Person7', 'transaction1', 1.5, 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Person_ID', 'transaction_ID', 'variable_1', 'variable_2'])

dfnew = df #create a copy

new_column = df['Person_ID'] #you gonna use this column to insert its values

for column, values in df.iteritems(): #fill every cell with -10
  dfnew[column] = -10

dfnew.insert(0, 'New_Column_Person_ID', new_column) #insert values of the first column

unique_values=df.groupby('Person_ID')['Person_ID'].nunique()

index_unique_values = pd.DataFrame(unique_values.index)

z = pd.concat([dfnew, index_unique_values], ignore_index=True) #concat instead of append method

z.reindex(z.index.repeat(3)) #repeat rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = 6
i = 'Person_ID'

s = df[i].value_counts().rsub(n)
pd.concat([pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({**{i:k},**dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference([i]),-10)},index = np.arange(v)) for k,v in s.items()]),df]).sort_values(i)
```

Output:

```
  Person_ID transaction_ID  variable_1  variable_2  variable_3 variable_X
0   person1            -10         -10         -10         -10        -10
1   person1            -10         -10         -10         -10        -10
2   person1            -10         -10         -10         -10        -10
0   person1   transaction1         123           0           1        abc
1   person1   transaction2         456           1           0        def
2   person1   transaction3         123           0           1        abc
0   personx            -10         -10         -10         -10        -10
1   personx            -10         -10         -10         -10        -10
2   personx            -10         -10         -10         -10        -10
3   personx            -10         -10         -10         -10        -10
3   personx   transaction1         123           0           1        abc
4   personx   transaction2         456           0           1        def
```